# PHP array loop and format

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.1

I am very new to PHP, learning fast but not fast enough! I am also learning Laravel 5.1.

I am trying to build a HTML select list array from an Eloquent query output, in the correct format for form builder (`Form::select`).

I have the following call to Eloquent to pull the data:

```
// Get list of States for address select
$states = State::all()->toArray();
```

It returns the following array:

```
array:8 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => "1"
    "state" => "ACT"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => "2"
    "state" => "NSW"
  ]
  ...
];
```

I want to loop through it and generate the following output:

```
array = [
   ''  => 'State',       <-- This is the default for the select list
   '1' => 'ACT',
   '2' => 'NSW',
   ...
];
```

I am using Laravel 5.1, so I am using the included `array_add()` function in my helper.

I call my function like this:

```
$states = create_select_list($states, 'State');
```

I next want to format the output so it is ready for the `Form::select` statement. I have tried the code below (as the final try from a few iterations!) but unsuccessfully.

```
function create_select_list($data, $default)
{
    // Declare array and set up default select item
    $container = ['' => $default];

    // Loop through data entries and build select list array
    foreach($data as list($entry, list($key, $value))) {
        $container = array_add($container, $key, $value);
    }

    // Return the select list array
    return $container;
}
```

All help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Isn't there some sort of "prompt" option in Laravel's `Form::select`? Because, that "State" you're trying to add is just a HTML attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop like below:

```
foreach($data as $key => $keyArr ) {
    $container = array_add($container, $keyArr['id'], $keyArr['state']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not about loop fix. I think previous comment should help you.

Just another idea. You can try use array_map instead foreach for this case.

For example:

```
$states = ['' => 'State'];

array_map(function($item) use (&$states) {
    $states[$item['id']] = $item['state'];
}, State::all()->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `list()` in your `foreach` loop, instead try:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $container = array_add($container, $key, $value);
}
```

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) gives a good overview of what `list()` actually does.